# Windows 8 not running after installing ubuntu

Tags: 12.04

I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 in my HP laptop alongside windows 8 but after installation, the bootloader failed to run windows 8. I have windows 7 also in the other drive but ubuntu bootloader did not show the windows 7. How to solve this problem?

Comment: I know this doesn't help at all, but my brother just wiped Win 8 completely off the laptop because each time he booted Win 8 it automatically ran "disk repair" and jacked up his Ubuntu.  If you can live without Win 8, or with it in a VM that's the way to go

Comment: @Freedom_Ben: Come on! I have three different PC's and on ecah I have Win7 or Win8 and Ubuntu 12.04 and everything works fine. It is just some issue or bug, which happens.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make sure you install Windows first. If, after installing Ubuntu you don't see Windows in the boot list try [configuring grub](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2).

Comment: Solved !!! I edited the windows 8 boot configuration file at start up and ran windows 8, then after Wrote on MBR with Windows 8 default boot os.

Comment: @poudelpavan When you have some time, you should write up some instructions of how you fixed it and post it as an answer for future generations